# how to update multiple records in sql

Tags: sql

Longitude is float column in sql table

Data for longitude columns is in positive number, I'm trying to add minus symbol before those values and make it negative for multiple rows.

If it is already Negative value, skip that row

can anyone suggest

Thanks

Comment: You could update all the rows where the longitude value is greater than zero, multiplying the longitude value by -1.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the values to be negative, use:

```
update t
    set longitude = - longitude
    where longitude > 0;
```